# How to extract 3d map data from OS X maps.app

Tags: 3d, maps

I want to extract the 3d Flyover map data from Apple's Maps.app for use in 3D modeling apps. Has anyone attempted this? The only maps files I could find were in:

```
/Library/Containers/com.apple.Maps/Data/Library/Saved Application State
```

This has a `window_1.data` file which is last modified today and is 2.8 MB, though I can't make out which format it is in.

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: ... what did you find?